# Need help configuring phabricator

Tags: apache, phabricator

I tired to configure phabricator with instructions of https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/
I configured my hostname to contain a dot.
I did everything in that descripion, but if i navigate to the hostname i set up, i only see default apache2 page and not phabricator. I'm not sure if i set up httpd.conf correctly since i dont find / -name httpd.conf on my system. I made suggested configuration at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf accourding to this information:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Debian.2C_Ubuntu_.28Apache_httpd_2.x.29:

When i    apache2ctl restart it says there are difficutlies to determine server's domain name. So /etc/hosts might be a problem, but since i see default apache2, server is up and running. Do you need to put a special :port to see phabricator's config?

Any help apprecieated.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to /etc/apache2/sites-available. Delete all *.conf files.

2) Create phabricator.conf file here with following content:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    # Change this to the domain which points to your host.
    ServerName yourservername

    # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it
    # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.
    #
    # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!
    DocumentRoot /path/to/phabricator/webroot

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]

    <Directory "/path/to/phabricator/webroot">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

3) make sure that you enter correct path for your phabricator directory in phabricator.conf.

4) Go to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. Delete all symlinks.

5) Execute the following commands:

```
sudo a2ensite phabricator
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

please do update this question if you still need help with the installation and I will gladly provide more information.  I think you need to add this after directory on httpd.conf:

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?**path**=$1  [B,L,QSA]

That might fix your problem.  Also make sure(for Ubuntu) you do have your documenROot and Directory end with "webroot" not webroot/.

-Apache port by default is 80 and Mysql port is 3306 by default.

The port on VirtualHost *:80 is Apache's port.  You need to keep this in mind as later on you will need to specify MySQL port on the MySQL configuration Page.